# Database-File with data android

Tags: android

Hi i am making an android app, and for the app i have a TON of question-answers sets , and i want to have them in the app , but i don't wanna write them down every time when  the app starts, so i started thinking database or a file with the Q&A with-in.

So in order to do so ,i created a database , but after a while i realized that i am putting the data in the database , and the very next line i am taking the data out of it, so the most logical way doing so is having a FILE ( or something else ) already filed with the data, and every time i need some data from there i can just read it.

So my question is-- Should i write a .txt file with ALL THE Q&A with-in , or something else, and if i DO write a .txt file where to store it in the res folder in the assets.

Thanks

Comment: `something else`, as you were correctly doing before "realizing", is using a db. Once you filled it with all your questions and all your answers (2 tables), you're ready to show your questions and then your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the Next link that Shows the Storage Options in Android Devices
[Android Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)
i recommand u go SQLite if DB is important to u..